# How to form a table name from concatenating strings in Select Statement in SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to achieve this -

```
SELECT * FROM A1234
```

I have the the ID 1234 saved in another table called Aliases which has two columns Alias,ID with one record like this.

Alias = TestTable, ID = 1234

So I am trying something like this

```
SELECT * FROM ('A'+ (SELECT ID FROM Aliases WHERE Alias = 'TestTable'))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have to do this in one step, or could you use some procedural tSQL code?

Comment: So, you have tables named `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, ..., `A1234`, ...?

Comment: If you have to change your criteria every time (`alias='TestTable'`), how is that any better than just changing the table name?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you choose the accepted answer? It was posted last.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @Q VARCHAR(MAX),@ID INT
SET @ID=(Select DISTINCT ID from Aliases where Alias = 'TestTable') -- CHECK TO RETURN JUST ON RESULT
SET @Q='SELECT * FROM A'+CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(10))
EXEC(@Q)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need dynamic SQL for this.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT TOP (1) @sql = N'SELECT * FROM A' + RTRIM(ID) + ';' 
  FROM dbo.Aliases WHERE Alias = 'TestTable';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

To build a set of statements that selects all of them, you can say:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
  SELECT *, ''A' + RTRIM(ID) + ''' FROM A' + RTRIM(ID) + ';'
FROM dbo.Aliases;

PRINT @sql;

-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: +1: If you feel like being verbose you could add the cursor answer so he can pull information from all the tables in the [Aliases] table and possibly even reference the system tables to return all unique columns by type for all the tables and create/populate the table. =D

Comment: @Love2Learn sure, but you don't need all the scaffolding of a cursor for that, you can just concatenate...

Comment: Not sure I follow, I know you could use concatenation to build out a variable to use against the system tables to identify the columns, but you'd still need a cursor to dynamically query all the table from the column of table names in [Aliases], right???

Comment: @Love2Learn see my update. What does a cursor do that this code doesn't?

Comment: Yeah, but what if you wanted to query across many databases on a remote server and were going to build out the querystring and embed it in an `OpenQuery`; then you might run into a length limitation of your @sql variable. (This is a joke, you are right.)